# Oracle - Substitute substrings of records by a list of regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I want to clean a table of alphanumeric (varchar2) records. Each single record should be checked for containing a set of dirtywords, which should be replaced in case of. The patterns and replacements are stored in a seperate table.

**Example:**

```
create table to_clean (
text_id number,
dirty_text  varchar2(4000));

insert into to_clean values(1,'hello this is my dirtyword1 text.');
insert into to_clean values(2,'hello this is my dirtyword3 text.');
insert into to_clean values(3,'hello this is my dirtyword2 dirtyword1  text.');

create table regex_list(
pattern varchar2(400),
replacement varchar2(400));

insert into regex_list values('dirtyword1','clean1');
insert into regex_list values('dirtyword2',' '); --remove totally
insert into regex_list values('dirtyword3','clean3');
```

Pseudocode:

```
for each dirty_text in to_clean
    for pattern, replacement in regexlist
        regex_replace(dirty_text, pattern, replacement)
```

What would be the most performant way to solve this in Oracle?  `regex_list` contains regular expressions AND plain strings as patterns. I only want to replace complete words, not partial words (so separated by whitespace)

Comment: The original table has to remain unchanged, so the replacement is only necessary for the select.

Comment: Do you actually have regular expressions in the `regex_list` table?  Or just strings to replace?  Do you want to replace partial words?  If your `to_clean` table had a string "Somedirtyword1InTheMiddle" would you want to replace that?  Or do you only want to replace complete words?

Comment: regex_list contains regular expressions AND plane strings as patterns.
I only want to replace complete words, no partial words (so seperated by a following whitespace)

Comment: I assume you could have a dirty_text value with multiple dirty words such as `'hello this is my dirtyword1 and dirtyword2 text.'`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE to_clean c
   SET dirty_text =
          (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (dirty_text, pattern, replacement) replaced
             FROM    regex_list r
                  INNER JOIN
                     (SELECT t.*,
                             (SELECT pattern
                                FROM regex_list
                               WHERE INSTR (T.DIRTY_TEXT, pattern) <> 0)
                                find_pat
                        FROM to_clean t) s
                  ON (r.pattern = s.find_pat)
            WHERE c.dirty_text = dirty_text);
```

If you have expressions, instead words, instr doesn't works, then use regexp_like (as Justin Cave said):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (dirty_text, pattern, replacement) replaced
             FROM    regex_list r
                  INNER JOIN
                     (SELECT t.*,
                             (SELECT pattern
                                FROM regex_list
                               WHERE regexp_like(T.DIRTY_TEXT,pattern) )
                                find_pat
                        FROM to_clean t) s
                  ON (r.pattern = s.find_pat)
```

**EDIT**

In that case you can use plsql. Please take a look at this:

```
--Create oracle objects
create or replace type clean_o as object(text_id number,dirty_text varchar2(500));
create or replace type clean_t as table of clean_o; 

--Function
create or replace function clean_text return clean_t pipelined is 
    cursor clean_c is select * from to_clean;
    text varchar2(250);
begin
    for c in clean_c loop
       text:= c.dirty_text; 
       for i in (select * from regex_list) loop
          text:= regexp_replace(text,i.pattern,i.replacement);  
       end loop;
       PIPE ROW (clean_o(c.text_id,text));
    end loop;
end;
```

Now you can do this:

```
select * from table(clean_text)
```

Comment: Amazing, that really works!. I just removed the update part, because I only need the substitution in a select, not phiscally on the dirt_text table.
Wow, I was sure I had to use PL/SQL with nested for-loops here!

Comment: Note that this will replace partial words (i.e. dirtyWord1 in ""Somedirtyword1InTheMiddle") rather than just whole words.  The `instr` would need to be replaced with a `regexp_like` to handle regular expressions in the `pattern`.  And you'd probably want your "plain strings" in the `regex_list` table to be regular expressions that implement your "whole word" logic (i.e. either the beginning of the string or a leading whitespace character, a trailing white space or punctuation character or the end of the string).

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comment

Comment: Yes @JustinCave, you are right, but in this case, he wants to remove words not expresions, so instr can look for a word perfectly, in other case i will be agreed with you. Thanks

Comment: @Aramillo - Based on the comments on the question (which need to get edited in to the question), the real `regex_list` table has regular expressions and plain words.

Comment: `INSTR()` could be replaced with `REGEXP_INSTR()`, but I don't see that that would gain anything over `REGEXP_LIKE()` in this instance.

Comment: @Aaramillo: Actually I fogot to mention, that table structure of table "to_clean" has an additional column. I updated it. Now I get an error: ORA-01427- "single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Comment: Yes, I get the ORA-01427 when invoking the DML above too.

Comment: Aramillo's solution only works, if there is only **1** dirtyword in a row. It fails with multible matches.

Comment: Can you please post the sample data where you get this conclusion. With actual test data it's working, even with the new to_clean table field.

Comment: Man, you're an OCP, aren't you? Thanks for the great effort, will test it tomorrow.

Comment: GGG, I wish that man, i'm just another boy who likes oracle. I really appreciate your comment and really hope this helps.:)

Comment: In my real life table I unfortunately get an ORA-06502: PL/SQL numeric or value error: character to number conversion error. I already eliminated the the null values, but didn't help. Error is located in line 10, PIPE ROW (clean_o(c.text_id,text));

Comment: Solved it myself, in that line I had the attributes in a wrong order. Works now perfectly, thanks again!